# Cannot find any resources in SAM template

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, yaml, jetbrains-rider

I wrote a lambda aws function on JetBrains Rider, and while trying to get to deploy the template.yaml file i get an aws tools error with the content

> Cannot find any resources in SAM template project_path/template.yaml

.yaml file content:

```
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  Sample SAM Template for lambda
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 900
    
    
Metadata:
  AWS::ServerlessRepo::Application:
    Name: report_serverless
    Description: report_serverless
    Author: user
    
Resources:
  ReportServerlessFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function  
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./data/
      Handler: report_serverless::report_serverless.Function::FunctionHandler
      Runtime: dotnetcore3.1
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Environment: 
        Variables:
          VaultApiHost: *******
          VaultApiToken: *******
          VaultCertificate: ****
          ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
          
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - *******
        SubnetIds:
          - *********
          - *********
          - *********

      FileSystemConfigs:
        - Arn: !GetAtt AccessPoint.Arn 
          LocalMountPath: /mnt/efs
          
      Events:
        ReportServerless:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /report
            Method: get
      Policies:
        - Statement:
            - Sid: AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - logs:CreateLogGroup
                - logs:CreateLogStream
                - logs:PutLogEvents
                - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
              Resource: "*"
            - Sid: AmazonElasticFileSystemClientFullAccess
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - elasticfilesystem:ClientMount
                - elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess
                - elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite
                - elasticfilesystem:DescribeMountTargets
              Resource: "*"
  MyMountTarget:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: *********
      SecurityGroups:
        - *********
      SubnetId: ********
      
  AccessPoint:
    Type: AWS::EFS::AccessPoint
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: ***********

Outputs:
  ReportServerlessApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Report Serverless function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  ReportServerlessFunction:
    Description: "Report Serverless Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt ReportServerlessFunction.Arn
  ReportServerlessFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Report Serverless function"
    Value: !GetAtt ReportServerlessRole.Arn
```

and trying to deploy from console returns

> Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: sam-app, ex: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: T
> emplate error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource ReportServerlessRole

using the Sam validate code replies the file is valid, and also ReportServerlessRole.Arn is created

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a copy/ paste issue, but is your template missing a line at the very top?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
```

Comment: Sadly it is a copy/ paste issue, but thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error because `template.yaml` was inside a directory which I previously marked as `Excluded` in PyCharm. This directory wasn't indexed and for some reason that caused deployment failures.

**The solution was to Cancel Exclusion** (right click on a directory containing `template.yaml` -> Mark Directory as -> Cancel Exclusion). That triggered the indexing and after that I was able to deploy.

Note:
The directory can be marked as `Excluded` again and the deployment will still work. But this is probably not the best idea because deployment would rely on the previously generated indexes which might be outdated if directory content has changed. Additionally, exclusion would have to be canceled each time the indexes are cleared (e.g. PyCharm cache invalidation).